# Chrome webextensions: how to get content-length header using fetch api

Tags: google-chrome-extension, http-headers, fetch, content-length

I'm developing a chrome webextension and I'm trying to use fetch api to get `content-length` header using a code similar with

```
fetch("http://example.com/", {
    method: "GET"
}).then(response => console.log(response.headers.get("content-length")));
```

But I get a `null` value in console. Why?

Other info:

- I have `<all_urls>` permission in extension manifest
- The same code works ok in firefox version of this webextension
- The `XMLHTTPRequest` variant works ok in chrome, so probably I'm missing some extra parameters to fetch function

Comment: Use XMLHttpRequest instead. BTW if you don't need the response body, method 'head' is sufficient. More info: [Reading response headers with Fetch API](//stackoverflow.com/a/44816592)

Comment: That's strange, because the same fetch code works in Firefox. Maybe is Chrome fetch implementation incomplete? Hope it's no permanent design decision.

Comment: Well, the standard itself for Fetch is incomplete so I'm not surprised there are bugs or inconsistencies in implementations. You can report it on https://crbug.com if it wasn't reported already.

Comment: From [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=841308&q=component%3ABlink%3ENetwork%3EFetchAPI%20&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified) it seems that problem will be solved specifically for `content-length` header, but this is not a real solution (I also need `content-disposition` header)

Comment: Hey, yes @AndyBolona - if you want to you can argue the case I argued for content-length for content-disposition - here is my PR: https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/pull/626 and issue: https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/622 - if you have a good reason then the spec people are really nice. Also feel free to ping me about it